# Bcrypt: invalid ELF header with Docker and Sails.JS

Tags: node.js, docker, sails.js, bcrypt

My Node `Dockfile`:

```
# Set the base image to ubuntu
FROM ubuntu

# Define working directory
ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src

# Install Node.js & other dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get -y install curl && \
        apt-get -y install sudo && \
        curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash - && \
        apt-get -y install python build-essential nodejs

RUN npm install -g node-gyp && \
        node-gyp clean && \
        npm cache clean

RUN node -v

# Install nodemon
RUN npm install -g nodemon


ADD package.json /src/package.json
RUN cd /src && npm install


# Expose port
EXPOSE  8080

# Run app using nodemon
CMD npm install; nodemon /src/app.js
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    links:
        - node1:node1
        - node2:node2
        - node3:node3
    ports:
        - "80:80"
redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
        - "6379"
node1:
    build: ./node
    links:
        - redis
    ports:
        - "8080"
node2:
    build: ./node
    links:
        - redis
    ports:
        - "8080"
node3:
    build: ./node
    links:
        - redis
    ports:
        - "8080"
```

`docker-compose build` runs successfully and Redis/Nginx setup correcly on `docker-compose up` but the node instances throw this error:

```
node2_1 | /src/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
node2_1 |         throw e
node2_1 |               ^
node2_1 | Error: /src/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
node2_1 |     at Error (native)
node2_1 |     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
node2_1 |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
node2_1 |     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
node2_1 |     at require (module.js:384:17)
node2_1 |     at bindings (/src/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
node2_1 |     at Object.<anonymous> (/src/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
node2_1 |     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
node2_1 |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
node2_1 |     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
node2_1 |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
node2_1 |     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
node2_1 |     at require (module.js:384:17)
node2_1 |     at Object.<anonymous> (/src/api/models/User.js:10:14)
node2_1 |     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
node2_1 |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
node2_1 | 19 Aug 20:21:11 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've searched all over and can't seem to find a solution that works. I've tried using the regular setup url: `https://deb.nodesource.com/setup`, specifically installing `python2.7`, and using the `ubuntu:15.04` image.

I've read that this happens when people try to use bcrypt on a linux env after it was built on a OS X (my OS), but I don't think that would be the issue since I'm building everything using docker and boot2docker.

Comment: Can you show a complete reproducer?

Comment: What do you mean by 'reproducer'?

Comment: The shortest code that allows anybody to do exacty the  same as you

Comment: If the previous responses haven't worked, switching from [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) to [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I was using a Linux Docker image on Windows. Running `npm install` on Windows synced the files to the Docker image. Deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` inside the container fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my package config I had `"bcrypt":"^0.8.0"` and when I took out the `^` and changed it to `"bcrypt":"0.8.0"` I was able to get everything running.

The issue was that it was trying to run bcrypt 0.8.5 and that was causing issues for some reason.

Comment: It would be great to know what is causing the issue. I checked the [Changelog](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/blob/v0.8.7/CHANGELOG.md) but nothing stands out to me.

Comment: @Lucas If this is still happening to you, try to delete the node_modules folder and do a fresh `npm install` in the docker container. Bcrypt needs to be built on the architecture it's running on, so if you are copying it from OS X to linux then it needs to get re-built. Though I don't remember if this was also part of the problem for this issue.

Comment: The developers decided to introduce breaking changes, seen in Issue #150 https://github.com/barrysteyn/node-scrypt/issues/150

"okay, I have no problem with throwing an error."

Answer (score 43):

Make sure that you are not copying the `node_modules` folder. I got this error when using the official nodejs "onbuild" image which would copy everything...

Now I use:

.dockerignore

```
node_modules
```

dockerfile

```
FROM node:6.4.0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

EXPOSE 6969
```

**Edit**: The official NodeJS Docker starter image project on Github has accepted my pull request for ther README which instructs to explicitly ignore the node_modules.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that I have to rebuild the docker image each time I change something in my app's code? And if so it can take a while to see the changes live if I have a lot of dependencies in my `package.json` and `npm install` takes a lot of time. It isn't suited for development purposes in that case.

Answer (score 29):

I was experiencing same thing, even though using Express, not Sails. I tried every suggestion here with no success. What made the trick was change the npm module bcrypt by bcryptjs:

```
npm uninstall bcrypt
npm install bcryptjs --save
```

Then change your require to something like

```
var bcrypt   = require('bcryptjs');
```

It is working flawlessly now.

Comment: Try to format this as an answer based on the S.O. guidelines! Thank you!

Comment: bcrypt-nodejs is no longer maintained - DO NOT USE IT Instead use bcryptjs

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: This is the best solution. 
ignoring node modules is not optimal during development. However during staging and production ignoring node modules makes sense, as one will not be changing them as often as dev code. Also, binary bindings may differ sometimes if the developer is doing cross platform developement.

Answer (score 3):

just to add a new possible cause. I tried to build my docker image for a nodejs app but i've gotthe error `invalid ELF header`. In my case 
i ve resolved the issue by adding the `node_modules/*`  from the .dockerignore file.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that excluding the entire local `node_modules` directory does not allow you to install npm packages and have your docker container track those changes in the container on the fly. I will have to rebuild my container each time. To avoid this specify only the bcrypt directory in the container volume and allow docker to track changes when other packages are installed or removed:

```
volumes: 
  - .:/app
  - /app/node_modules/bcrypt/
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way that allowed me to solve this problem, I think this can helps you also in Docker, just add to the run instructions on you docker file this instructions

**1. Uninstall bcrypt**

```
npm uninstall bcrypt
```

**2.- Install bcrypt again**

```
npm i bcrypt
```

**Edit this part of your docker file adding the lines**

```
ADD package.json /src/package.json
RUN cd /src && npm install


#Solve the problem reinstaling bcrypt
RUN npm uninstall bcrypt
RUN npm i bcrypt


# Expose port
EXPOSE  8080
```

The error occurs because when you install bcypt, npm installs the recommended version for your machine and operating system, but when you are on another machine, this doesn't work.

**-------- UPDATE ----------------------------------------**

It also seems to me that another solution which is to grant root permissions to bcrypt installation, it happens because bcryp uses its own user but it has no permissions, so:

**1. You must grant root permission to your project folder. go outside of your project folder and then**

```
sudo su
```

***Then enter your root password to get root user permissions***

**2. Grant permission to your project folder**

```
chmod -R 777 <project_folder>
```

**3. Go to your project folder and install bcrypt**

```
cd <project_folder>
```

**AND**

```
npm i bcrypt --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root --save
```

Ready, if everything was OK, your bcrypt module will install without problems.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is => Docker Context. Docker context is copying everything from your root folder to destination container working directory.

So you have to add a .dockerignore file and add these entries (with any other files that you want to ignore)

- node_modules
- npm-debug.log

And now when you will build your container, it will build everything as per container's OS.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to run `bcrypt` in a `docker container` using `docker-copmpose`. Container worked under `Linux`, but the development was carried out in `Windows`, and it was necessary to mount the volume with the code, but bcrypt created conflicting files. So I leave this review in the future.
bcrypt must only be installed inside the container, and copy to isolate. For example to block directory, or send to dev/null

```
    volumes:
      - ${WORKER_DIR}/api:${HOME}/api
      - /dev/null/:/api/node_modules/bcrypt/
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed it by adding these lines to Dockerfile

```
CMD [ "npm", "uninstall", "bcrypt" ]
CMD [ "npm", "install", "bcrypt" ]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Including a .dockerignore file fixed this error for me

The basic `.dockerignore` looks like this

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about 

ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```