# Bcrypt error in docker container. Error: /path/to/local/module/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, npm-install, bcrypt

I am running a containerized app using nodejs. I understand that I can add `node_modules` folder to my `.dockerignore` file and have the container install the dependencies itself. However, I have a slightly different usecase.
The `bcrypt` error is coming from a local node module I created that was installed in the containerized application using `npm install --save ./path/to/my/module`. The local module has a dependency on `bcrypt`.

I don't know how to ensure the bcrypt in this module is only installed in the container and not my machine.

Here are some codes from the containerized app

package.json

```
{
  "name": "utme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "UTME App",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "node ./dist/index.js",
    "watch": "nodemon -L --exec \"npm run start\" --watch src --ext ts"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "exam-app-core": "file:../../libs/exam-app-core", // local node module dependency that has a dependency on bcrypt
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.10",
    "@types/sinon": "^10.0.6",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "sinon": "^12.0.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-slim

ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH /home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
RUN npm i npm@latest mocha@latest -g


WORKDIR /usr/src/app/utme

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

CMD [ "npm", "run", "watch" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
        - .env.docker
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    healthcheck:
      disable: true
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app/utme
        - ../../libs/exam-app-core:/usr/src/libs/exam-app-core
        - /usr/src/app/utme/node_modules
    networks:
        - database-net

networks:
  database-net:
    external: true
    name: services_net
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105251/bcrypt-invalid-elf-header-with-docker-and-sails-js ?

Comment: Thanks Daantje, your reference helped. I changed my dep from bcrypt to bcryptjs